# IOS/Xcode: Crash due to lack of plist key for calendars not responding to adding keys

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I am trying to run a tutorial on EventKit.  The tutorial was written before Apple required you to include plist keys for privacy-sensitive things like accessing a calendar so I got the error in Xcode:

This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Accordingly, I went to the plist file and added keys for both calendar and reminders as shown here:

[image]

The source code now includes the following keys:

```
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Reminders</string>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Calendars</string>
```

I also deleted the project from the simulator, cleaned it and reloaded.  However, I am still getting the original error.  Is there anything else I can try?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: I don't really think it will have an effect but try making it be more than a one word string for each description. Try a full sentence. It's possible there is a check that treats a one word description like no description.

Comment: I added a bunch of words but same error

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it would help. I missed that you had the wrong plist file selected, even after I looked to see if you had the wrong one… must be nap time…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are editing the wrong `Info.plist` file.
You should edit the Info.plist file of your main target (should be called EventKitDemo-Info.plist). From your screenshot it seems that you're editing the Info.plist of the test target.

Comment: Thank you.  That was it!